# Flex AdvancedDataGrid show image in cell

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I want to display image in cell, when one property of my class is set to True value.
I don't know how to do it. I declared my icon:

```
[Bindable]
[Embed("/icons/activate.png")]
private var _alert:Class;
```

And now i want to use something simillar to labelFunction to check the specific value and put corrent incon into cell.

This is my column:

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Modified" dataField="IsModified"   >
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use itemrenderers:

```
<mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Modified" dataField="IsModified" 
            itemRenderer="myItemRenderer"/>
```

and in myItemRenderer class:

```
<mx:HBox xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    horizontalAlign="center" >
    <mx:Image source="{ _alert }" visible="{ data.showImage }" />
</mx:HBox>
```

more on the itemrenderers: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=cellrenderer_7.html